# How to debug error while compiling gwt source: "An unexpected error has been detected by Java Runtime Environment"?

Tags: java, gwt, ant, ubuntu

While compiling gwt source, I get the error :

```
"An unexpected error has been detected by Java Runtime Environment "
```

Following is the `hs_err_pid14267.log` (error log) file is generated on server

How would you debug this?

```
#
# An unexpected error has been detected by Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f8d00a8d25a, pid=14267, tid=140243142814032
#
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (10.0-b22 mixed mode linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x1f125a]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000000004019a800):  JavaThread "CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=14276, stack(0x00007f8ce6a5a000,0x00007f8ce6b5b000)]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr=0x0000000000000000

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000000, RBX=0x00007f8ce018cae0, RCX=0x00000000401cfc00, RDX=0x0000000000000053
RSP=0x00007f8ce6b56bf0, RBP=0x00007f8ce6b56c60, RSI=0x00000000401cfc00, RDI=0x00007f8ce018cae0
R8 =0x00000000401cfc58, R9 =0x00000000401cfc00, R10=0x00000000401cfc00, R11=0x0000000000000000
R12=0x00007f8ce018caa8, R13=0x0000000000000000, R14=0x00000000401240c0, R15=0x0000000000000001
RIP=0x00007f8d00a8d25a, EFL=0x0000000000010246, CSGSFS=0x000000000000e033, ERR=0x0000000000000004
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00007f8ce6b56bf0)
0x00007f8ce6b56bf0:   00000000408c6768 0000000effffffff
0x00007f8ce6b56c00:   00000000401cfc00 0000000200a31361
0x00007f8ce6b56c10:   00000000408c6760 00000011e6b57820
0x00007f8ce6b56c20:   00007f8ce6b578e8 01000000000006bd
0x00007f8ce6b56c30:   00007f8ce6b57820 00007f8d010d6910
0x00007f8ce6b56c40:   00007f8ce6b57820 00007f8ce6b56db0
0x00007f8ce6b56c50:   00007f8ce6b56d70 00007f8ce6b56d40
0x00007f8ce6b56c60:   00007f8ce6b56e80 00007f8d00a8c79c
0x00007f8ce6b56c70:   00007f8ce6b578e8 00007f8ce6b56e30
0x00007f8ce6b56c80:   00007f8ce0470a70 00007f8ce0000020
0x00007f8ce6b56c90:   00007f8ce6b56d00 00007f8d010efd10
0x00007f8ce6b56ca0:   00007f8ce10f21b0 0000000000000195
0x00007f8ce6b56cb0:   00007f8ce6b57940 00007f8d0128ec1c
0x00007f8ce6b56cc0:   00007f8ce6b5a950 00007f8ce6b56d00
0x00007f8ce6b56cd0:   00007f8d010f2480 00007f8ce00e3a00
0x00007f8ce6b56ce0:   0000000000000195 00007f8d00ec6d82
0x00007f8ce6b56cf0:   0000000040111fe0 00007f8d00ec6e51
0x00007f8ce6b56d00:   00007f8ce6b5a950 00007f8ce6b56d40
0x00007f8ce6b56d10:   00007f8d010f2480 0000000000007fe8
0x00007f8ce6b56d20:   00007f8ce00e3a00 00007f8d00ec6d82
0x00007f8ce6b56d30:   0000000040111fe0 00007f8d00ec6e51
0x00007f8ce6b56d40:   00007f8d010d6910 00007f8d0000000e
0x00007f8ce6b56d50:   00007f8ce6b591d0 00007f8ce6b57820
0x00007f8ce6b56d60:   00007f8c00000a6e 000000004019ac70
0x00007f8ce6b56d70:   000000000000000d 00007f8ce6b591d0
0x00007f8ce6b56d80:   00007f8ce0f9a3d0 00007f8d00a30d00
0x00007f8ce6b56d90:   00007f8ce017c460 00000000000006be
0x00007f8ce6b56da0:   00007f8ce6b56e30 0000000040fd7100
0x00007f8ce6b56db0:   000000000000000c 00007f8ce6b591d0
0x00007f8ce6b56dc0:   00007f8ce03da290 00007f8ce04909d0
0x00007f8ce6b56dd0:   000000004038c2e0 000000004038d040
0x00007f8ce6b56de0:   00000000410c8f80 00007f8ce6b57940 

Instructions: (pc=0x00007f8d00a8d25a)
0x00007f8d00a8d24a:   48 89 cf 41 ff 95 80 00 00 00 48 89 df 49 89 c5
0x00007f8d00a8d25a:   8b 00 41 21 44 24 38 41 8b 45 04 21 43 04 41 8b 

Stack: [0x00007f8ce6a5a000,0x00007f8ce6b5b000],  sp=0x00007f8ce6b56bf0,  free space=1010k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0x1f125a]
V  [libjvm.so+0x1f079c]
V  [libjvm.so+0x2445e5]
V  [libjvm.so+0x2410f5]
V  [libjvm.so+0x1e05f7]
V  [libjvm.so+0x248f88]
V  [libjvm.so+0x248926]
V  [libjvm.so+0x62a7a9]
V  [libjvm.so+0x624a51]
V  [libjvm.so+0x50628a]


Current CompileTask:
C2:553      org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ParameterizedMethodBinding.<init>(Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/lookup/ParameterizedTypeBinding;Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/lookup/MethodBinding;)V (596 bytes)


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x00000000404fb800 JavaThread "Timer-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14281, stack(0x00007f8ce63b8000,0x00007f8ce64b9000)]
  0x00000000401a7c00 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14278, stack(0x00007f8ce6858000,0x00007f8ce6959000)]
  0x00000000401a6000 JavaThread "CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14277, stack(0x00007f8ce6959000,0x00007f8ce6a5a000)]
=>0x000000004019a800 JavaThread "CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=14276, stack(0x00007f8ce6a5a000,0x00007f8ce6b5b000)]
  0x0000000040199400 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14275, stack(0x00007f8ce6b5b000,0x00007f8ce6c5c000)]
  0x0000000040177400 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14274, stack(0x00007f8ce6c5c000,0x00007f8ce6d5d000)]
  0x0000000040176000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14273, stack(0x00007f8ce6d5d000,0x00007f8ce6e5e000)]
  0x0000000040114000 JavaThread "main" [_thread_blocked, id=14271, stack(0x00007f8d0051a000,0x00007f8d0061b000)]

Other Threads:
  0x0000000040170c00 VMThread [stack: 0x00007f8ce6e5e000,0x00007f8ce6f5f000] [id=14272]
  0x00000000401a9c00 WatcherThread [stack: 0x00007f8ce6757000,0x00007f8ce6858000] [id=14279]

VM state:at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread:  ([mutex/lock_event])
[0x0000000040110c10/0x0000000040110c60] Threads_lock - owner thread: 0x0000000040170c00
[0x00000000401113b0/0x00000000401113e0] Heap_lock - owner thread: 0x0000000040114000

Heap
 def new generation   total 46272K, used 46271K [0x00007f8ce7270000, 0x00007f8cea4a0000, 0x00007f8cec7c0000)
  eden space 41152K, 100% used [0x00007f8ce7270000, 0x00007f8ce9aa0000, 0x00007f8ce9aa0000)
  from space 5120K,  99% used [0x00007f8ce9fa0000, 0x00007f8cea49fff0, 0x00007f8cea4a0000)
  to   space 5120K,   0% used [0x00007f8ce9aa0000, 0x00007f8ce9aa1330, 0x00007f8ce9fa0000)
 tenured generation   total 102736K, used 83819K [0x00007f8cec7c0000, 0x00007f8cf2c14000, 0x00007f8cf7270000)
   the space 102736K,  81% used [0x00007f8cec7c0000, 0x00007f8cf199ae58, 0x00007f8cf199b000, 0x00007f8cf2c14000)
 compacting perm gen  total 21248K, used 13511K [0x00007f8cf7270000, 0x00007f8cf8730000, 0x00007f8cfc670000)
   the space 21248K,  63% used [0x00007f8cf7270000, 0x00007f8cf7fa1cf0, 0x00007f8cf7fa1e00, 0x00007f8cf8730000)
No shared spaces configured.

Dynamic libraries:
40000000-40009000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 690654                             /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.06/jre/bin/java
40108000-4010a000 rwxp 00008000 08:01 690654                             /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.06/jre/bin/java
4010a000-42c52000 rwxp 4010a000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f8ce0000000-7f8ce1a00000 rwxp 7f8ce0000000 00:00 0 
7f8ce1a00000-7f8ce4000000 ---p 7f8ce1a00000 00:00 0 
7f8ce63af000-7f8ce63b3000 r-xs 000ca000 08:01 690555                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.06/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar
7f8ce63b3000-7f8ce63b5000 r-xs 00001000 08:01 690554                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.06/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar
7f8ce63b5000-7f8ce63b8000 r-xs 00027000 08:01 690553                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.06/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar
7f8ce63b8000-7f8ce63bb000 ---p 7f8ce63b8000 00:00 0 
7f8ce63bb000-7f8ce64b9000 rwxp 7f8ce63bb000 00:00 0 
7f8ce64b9000-7f8ce64bd000 r-xs 00069000 08:01 935693                     /root/Workspace/Giskard/dev/Giskard/war/WEB-INF/lib/mysql-connector-java-3.1.12-bin.jar
7f8ce64bd000-7f8ce64bf000 r-xs 00001000 08:01 935633                     /root/Workspace/Giskard/dev/Giskard/war/WEB-INF/lib/jta.jar
7f8ce64bf000-7f8ce64c2000 r-xs 0002b000 08:01 935618                     /root/Workspace/Giskard/dev/Giskard/war/WEB-INF/lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar
7f8ce64c2000-7f8ce64c7000 r-xs 00027000 08:01 935690                     /root/Workspace/Giskard/dev/Giskard/war/WEB-INF/lib/jdo2-api-2.3-SNAPSHOT.jar
7f8ce64c7000-7f8ce64e9000 r-xs 0020a000 08:01 935660                     /root/Workspace/Giskard/dev/Giskard/war/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate3.jar
7f8ce64e9000-7f8ce64ef000 r-xs 00050000 08:01 935684                     /root/Workspace/Giskard/dev/Giskard/war/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-tools.jar
7f8ce64ef000-7f8ce64f2000 r-xs 0000e000 08:01 935615                     /root/Workspace/Giskard/dev/Giskard/war/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-commons-annotations.jar
7f8ce64f2000-7f8ce64f7000 r-xs 00040000 08:01 935672                     /root/Workspace/Giskard/dev/Giskard/war/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-annotations.jar
7f8ce64f7000-7f8ce6511000 r-xs 000cb000 08:01 935651                     /root/Workspace/Giskard/dev/Giskard/war/WEB-INF/lib/gwt-servlet.jar
7f8ce6511000-7f8ce6512000 r-xs 00003000 08:01 935642                     /root/Workspace/Giskard/dev/Giskard/war/WEB-INF/lib/geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar
7f8ce6512000-7f8ce6515000 r-xs 0000a000 08:01 935627                     /root/Workspace/Giskard/dev/Giskard/war/WEB-INF/lib/geronimo-jpa_3.0_spec-1.1.1.jar
7f8ce6515000-7f8ce6523000 r-xs 000b6000 08:01 935648                     /root/Workspace/Giskard/dev/Giskard/war/WEB-INF/lib/freemarker.jar
7f8ce6523000-7f8ce6526000 r-xs 0000a000 08:01 935612                     /root/Workspace/Giskard/dev/Giskard/war/WEB-INF/lib/ejb3-persistence.jar
7f8ce6526000-7f8ce652b000 r-xs 00048000 08:01 935630                     /root/Workspace/Giskard/dev/Giskard/war/WEB-INF/lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar
7f8ce652b000-7f8ce652e000 r-xs 0001f000 08:01 935621                     /root/Workspace/Giskard/dev/Giskard/war/WEB-INF/lib/datanucleus-jpa-1.1.0.jar
7f8ce652e000-7f8ce6548000 r-xs 001b9000 08:01 935669                     /root/Workspace/Giskard/dev/Giskard/war/WEB-INF/lib/datanucleus-core-1.1.0.jar
7f8ce6548000-7f8ce6577000 r-xs 00525000 08:01 935657                     /root/Workspace/Giskard/dev/Giskard/war/WEB-INF/lib/appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.2.0.jar
7f8ce6577000-7f8ce657a000 rwxp 7f8ce6577000 00:00 0 
7f8ce657a000-7f8ce6678000 rwxp 7f8ce657a000 00:00 0 
7f8ce6678000-7f8ce6706000 r-xs 00a0d000 08:01 918062                     /root/Workspace/gwt-linux-1.6.4/gwt-dev-linux.jar
7f8ce6706000-7f8ce6757000 r-xs 00318000 08:01 918142                     /root/Workspace/gwt-linux-1.6.4/gwt-user.jar
7f8ce6757000-7f8ce6758000 ---p 7f8ce6757000 00:00 0 
7f8ce6758000-7f8ce6858000 rwxp 7f8ce6758000 00:00 0 
7f8ce6858000-7f8ce685b000 ---p 7f8ce6858000 00:00 0 
7f8ce685b000-7f8ce6959000 rwxp 7f8ce685b000 00:00 0 
7f8ce6959000-7f8ce695c000 ---p 7f8ce6959000 00:00 0 
7f8ce695c000-7f8ce6a5a000 rwxp 7f8ce695c000 00:00 0 
7f8ce6a5a000-7f8ce6a5d000 ---p 7f8ce6a5a000 00:00 0 
7f8ce6a5d000-7f8ce6b5b000 rwxp 7f8ce6a5d000 00:00 0 
7f8ce6b5b000-7f8ce6b5e000 ---p 7f8ce6b5b000 00:00 0 
7f8ce6b5e000-7f8ce6c5c000 rwxp 7f8ce6b5e000 00:00 0 
7f8ce6c5c000-7f8ce6c5f000 ---p 7f8ce6c5c000 00:00 0 
7f8ce6c5f000-7f8ce6d5d000 rwxp 7f8ce6c5f000 00:00 0 
7f8ce6d5d000-7f8ce6d60000 ---p 7f8ce6d5d000 00:00 0 
7f8ce6d60000-7f8ce6e5e000 rwxp 7f8ce6d60000 00:00 0 
7f8ce6e5e000-7f8ce6e5f000 ---p 7f8ce6e5e000 00:00 0 
7f8ce6e5f000-7f8ce6f91000 rwxp 7f8ce6e5f000 00:00 0 
7f8ce6f91000-7f8ce711c000 r-xs 02df0000 08:01 690738                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.06/jre/lib/rt.jar
7f8ce711c000-7f8ce714f000 rwxp 7f8ce711c000 00:00 0 
7f8ce714f000-7f8ce716f000 rwxp 7f8ce714f000 00:00 0 
7f8ce716f000-7f8ce71a2000 rwxp 7f8ce716f000 00:00 0 
7f8ce71a2000-7f8ce71c5000 rwxp 7f8ce71a2000 00:00 0 
7f8ce71c5000-7f8ce71df000 rwxp 7f8ce71c5000 00:00 0 
7f8ce71df000-7f8ce71ef000 rwxp 7f8ce71df000 00:00 0 
7f8ce71ef000-7f8ce7222000 rwxp 7f8ce71ef000 00:00 0 
7f8ce7222000-7f8ce7245000 rwxp 7f8ce7222000 00:00 0 
7f8ce7245000-7f8ce7250000 rwxp 7f8ce7245000 00:00 0 
7f8ce7250000-7f8ce726f000 rwxp 7f8ce7250000 00:00 0 
7f8ce726f000-7f8cea4a0000 rwxp 7f8ce726f000 00:00 0 
7f8cea4a0000-7f8cec7c0000 rwxp 7f8cea4a0000 00:00 0 
7f8cec7c0000-7f8cf2c14000 rwxp 7f8cec7c0000 00:00 0 
7f8cf2c14000-7f8cf7270000 rwxp 7f8cf2c14000 00:00 0 
7f8cf7270000-7f8cf8730000 rwxp 7f8cf7270000 00:00 0 
7f8cf8730000-7f8cfc670000 rwxp 7f8cf8730000 00:00 0 
7f8cfc670000-7f8cfc673000 r-xs 00034000 08:01 690666                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.06/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar
7f8cfc673000-7f8cfc678000 r-xs 0002e000 08:01 935678                     /root/Workspace/Giskard/dev/Giskard/war/WEB-INF/lib/datanucleus-appengine-1.0.0.final.jar
7f8cfc678000-7f8cfc679000 r-xs 00007000 08:01 935681                     /root/Workspace/Giskard/dev/Giskard/war/WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging.jar
7f8cfc679000-7f8cfc67b000 r-xs 00008000 08:01 935675                     /root/Workspace/Giskard/dev/Giskard/war/WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
7f8cfc67b000-7f8cfca0b000 rwxp 7f8cfc67b000 00:00 0 
7f8cfca0b000-7f8cff67b000 rwxp 7f8cfca0b000 00:00 0 
7f8cff67b000-7f8cff689000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 690683                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.06/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so
7f8cff689000-7f8cff78b000 ---p 0000e000 08:01 690683                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.06/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so
7f8cff78b000-7f8cff78e000 rwxp 00010000 08:01 690683                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.06/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so
7f8cff78e000-7f8cff78f000 rwxp 7f8cff78e000 00:00 0 
7f8cff78f000-7f8cff7b7000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 690696                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.06/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
7f8cff7b7000-7f8cff8b7000 ---p 00028000 08:01 690696                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.06/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
7f8cff8b7000-7f8cff8be000 rwxp 00028000 08:01 690696                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.06/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
7f8cff8be000-7f8cff8cb000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 690678                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.06/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so
7f8cff8cb000-7f8cff9ca000 ---p 0000d000 08:01 690678                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.06/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so
7f8cff9ca000-7f8cff9cd000 rwxp 0000c000 08:01 690678                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.06/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so
7f8cff9cd000-7f8cff9d7000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 180361                     /lib/libnss_files-2.7.so
7f8cff9d7000-7f8cffbd7000 ---p 0000a000 08:01 180361                     /lib/libnss_files-2.7.so
7f8cffbd7000-7f8cffbd9000 rwxp 0000a000 08:01 180361                     /lib/libnss_files-2.7.so
7f8cffbd9000-7f8cffbe3000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 180363                     /lib/libnss_nis-2.7.so
7f8cffbe3000-7f8cffde2000 ---p 0000a000 08:01 180363                     /lib/libnss_nis-2.7.so
7f8cffde2000-7f8cffde4000 rwxp 00009000 08:01 180363                     /lib/libnss_nis-2.7.so
7f8cffde4000-7f8cffdec000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 180359                     /lib/libnss_compat-2.7.so
7f8cffdec000-7f8cfffeb000 ---p 00008000 08:01 180359                     /lib/libnss_compat-2.7.so
7f8cfffeb000-7f8cfffed000 rwxp 00007000 08:01 180359                     /lib/libnss_compat-2.7.so
7f8cfffed000-7f8d00003000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 180358                     /lib/libnsl-2.7.so
7f8d00003000-7f8d00202000 ---p 00016000 08:01 180358                     /lib/libnsl-2.7.so
7f8d00202000-7f8d00204000 rwxp 00015000 08:01 180358                     /lib/libnsl-2.7.so
7f8d00204000-7f8d00206000 rwxp 7f8d00204000 00:00 0 
7f8d00206000-7f8d0020d000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 690685                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.06/jre/lib/amd64/native_threads/libhpi.so
7f8d0020d000-7f8d0030e000 ---p 00007000 08:01 690685                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.06/jre/lib/amd64/native_threads/libhpi.so
7f8d0030e000-7f8d00310000 rwxp 00008000 08:01 690685                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.06/jre/lib/amd64/native_threads/libhpi.so
7f8d00310000-7f8d00311000 rwxp 7f8d00310000 00:00 0 
7f8d00311000-7f8d00319000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 180374                     /lib/librt-2.7.so
7f8d00319000-7f8d00518000 ---p 00008000 08:01 180374                     /lib/librt-2.7.so
7f8d00518000-7f8d0051a000 rwxp 00007000 08:01 180374                     /lib/librt-2.7.so
7f8d0051a000-7f8d0051d000 ---p 7f8d0051a000 00:00 0 
7f8d0051d000-7f8d0061b000 rwxp 7f8d0051d000 00:00 0 
7f8d0061b000-7f8d0069b000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 180354                     /lib/libm-2.7.so
7f8d0069b000-7f8d0089a000 ---p 00080000 08:01 180354                     /lib/libm-2.7.so
7f8d0089a000-7f8d0089c000 rwxp 0007f000 08:01 180354                     /lib/libm-2.7.so
7f8d0089c000-7f8d00f91000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 690702                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.06/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
7f8d00f91000-7f8d01090000 ---p 006f5000 08:01 690702                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.06/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
7f8d01090000-7f8d011da000 rwxp 006f4000 08:01 690702                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.06/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
7f8d011da000-7f8d01217000 rwxp 7f8d011da000 00:00 0 
7f8d01217000-7f8d0136f000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 180336                     /lib/libc-2.7.so
7f8d0136f000-7f8d0156f000 ---p 00158000 08:01 180336                     /lib/libc-2.7.so
7f8d0156f000-7f8d01572000 r-xp 00158000 08:01 180336                     /lib/libc-2.7.so
7f8d01572000-7f8d01574000 rwxp 0015b000 08:01 180336                     /lib/libc-2.7.so
7f8d01574000-7f8d01579000 rwxp 7f8d01574000 00:00 0 
7f8d01579000-7f8d0157b000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 180345                     /lib/libdl-2.7.so
7f8d0157b000-7f8d0177b000 ---p 00002000 08:01 180345                     /lib/libdl-2.7.so
7f8d0177b000-7f8d0177d000 rwxp 00002000 08:01 180345                     /lib/libdl-2.7.so
7f8d0177d000-7f8d01793000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 180371                     /lib/libpthread-2.7.so
7f8d01793000-7f8d01993000 ---p 00016000 08:01 180371                     /lib/libpthread-2.7.so
7f8d01993000-7f8d01995000 rwxp 00016000 08:01 180371                     /lib/libpthread-2.7.so
7f8d01995000-7f8d01999000 rwxp 7f8d01995000 00:00 0 
7f8d01999000-7f8d019b6000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 180327                     /lib/ld-2.7.so
7f8d019b7000-7f8d019bb000 r-xs 0001f000 08:01 935645                     /root/Workspace/Giskard/dev/Giskard/war/WEB-INF/lib/commons-digester-1.7.jar
7f8d019bb000-7f8d019c1000 r-xs 00024000 08:01 935663                     /root/Workspace/Giskard/dev/Giskard/war/WEB-INF/lib/commons-collections.jar
7f8d019c1000-7f8d019c7000 r-xs 00025000 08:01 935654                     /root/Workspace/Giskard/dev/Giskard/war/WEB-INF/lib/commons-collections-2.1.1.jar
7f8d019c7000-7f8d019cc000 r-xs 0002a000 08:01 935687                     /root/Workspace/Giskard/dev/Giskard/war/WEB-INF/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.jar
7f8d019cc000-7f8d019d2000 r-xs 0003f000 08:01 935636                     /root/Workspace/Giskard/dev/Giskard/war/WEB-INF/lib/cglib-2.1.3.jar
7f8d019d2000-7f8d019d3000 r-xs 00006000 08:01 935639                     /root/Workspace/Giskard/dev/Giskard/war/WEB-INF/lib/asm.jar
7f8d019d3000-7f8d019d5000 r-xs 00003000 08:01 935624                     /root/Workspace/Giskard/dev/Giskard/war/WEB-INF/lib/asm-attrs.jar
7f8d019d5000-7f8d019db000 r-xs 00067000 08:01 935666                     /root/Workspace/Giskard/dev/Giskard/war/WEB-INF/lib/antlr-2.7.6.jar
7f8d019db000-7f8d019ea000 rwxp 7f8d019db000 00:00 0 
7f8d019ea000-7f8d01a9b000 rwxp 7f8d019ea000 00:00 0 
7f8d01a9b000-7f8d01aa3000 rwxs 00000000 08:01 1097810                    /tmp/hsperfdata_root/14267
7f8d01aa3000-7f8d01aa5000 rwxp 7f8d01aa3000 00:00 0 
7f8d01aa5000-7f8d01aac000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 690669                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.06/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
7f8d01aac000-7f8d01bad000 ---p 00007000 08:01 690669                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.06/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
7f8d01bad000-7f8d01baf000 rwxp 00008000 08:01 690669                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.06/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
7f8d01baf000-7f8d01bb0000 rwxp 7f8d01baf000 00:00 0 
7f8d01bb1000-7f8d01bb2000 rwxp 7f8d01bb1000 00:00 0 
7f8d01bb2000-7f8d01bb3000 ---p 7f8d01bb2000 00:00 0 
7f8d01bb3000-7f8d01bb6000 rwxp 7f8d01bb3000 00:00 0 
7f8d01bb6000-7f8d01bb8000 rwxp 0001d000 08:01 180327                     /lib/ld-2.7.so
7fff09ba2000-7fff09bb8000 rwxp 7ffffffe9000 00:00 0                      [stack]
7fff09bfe000-7fff09c00000 r-xp 7fff09bfe000 00:00 0                      [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Xmx256M 
java_command: com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler com.wissen.giskard.Giskard
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.06/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.06/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.06/jre/../lib/amd64
SHELL=/bin/bash

Signal Handlers:
SIGSEGV: [libjvm.so+0x6616e0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGBUS: [libjvm.so+0x6616e0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGFPE: [libjvm.so+0x5044d0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGPIPE: [libjvm.so+0x5044d0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGXFSZ: [libjvm.so+0x5044d0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGILL: [libjvm.so+0x5044d0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGUSR1: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGUSR2: [libjvm.so+0x506740], sa_mask[0]=0x00000004, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGHUP: [libjvm.so+0x5064a0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGINT: [libjvm.so+0x5064a0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGTERM: [libjvm.so+0x5064a0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGQUIT: [libjvm.so+0x5064a0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004


---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS:lenny/sid

uname:Linux 2.6.24-23-xen #1 SMP Mon Jan 26 03:09:12 UTC 2009 x86_64
libc:glibc 2.7 NPTL 2.7 
rlimit: STACK 8192k, CORE 0k, NPROC 2112, NOFILE 1024, AS infinity
load average:0.81 0.18 0.12

CPU:total 4 (4 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 16 model 2 stepping 3, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, mmxext, 3dnow, 3dnowext, sse4a

Memory: 4k page, physical 262364k(3032k free), swap 524280k(277596k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (10.0-b22) for linux-amd64 JRE (1.6.0_06-b02), built on Mar 25 2008 01:03:02 by "java_re" with gcc 3.2.2 (SuSE Linux)

time: Wed Aug 19 12:44:51 2009
elapsed time: 19 seconds
```

Comment: @Kirtan: thanks a bunch for letting us know.

Answer (score 2):

[As VonC said, this is a JVM error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304270/how-to-debug-error-while-compiling-gwt-source-an-unexpected-error-has-been-dete/1304338#1304338), and is reported fixed in the current versions, so you should by all means upgrade.

If for some reason you need to use this specific version, you should disable compilation for some of the methods. In the command line this would translate to

```
-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/core/internal/dtree/DataTreeNode,forwardDeltaWith
-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/lookup/ParameterizedTypeBinding,<init>
-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/lookup/ParameterizedMethodBinding,<init>
```

or for ant

```
<java classname="com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler" classpathref="compileClassPath@{module}" fork="true" failonerror="true">
    ...
    <jvmarg value="-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/core/internal/dtree/DataTreeNode,forwardDeltaWith" />
    <jvmarg value="-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/lookup/ParameterizedTypeBinding,&lt;init&gt;" />
    <jvmarg value="-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/lookup/ParameterizedMethodBinding,&lt;init&gt;" />
```

You should see output similar to:

```
[java] CompilerOracle: exclude org/eclipse/core/internal/dtree/DataTreeNode.forwardDeltaWith
[java] CompilerOracle: exclude org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/lookup/ParameterizedTypeBinding.<init>
[java] CompilerOracle: exclude org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/lookup/ParameterizedMethodBinding.<init>
```

And the compilation will succeed.

Courtesy of [grack.com: GWT 1.6 crashes (and a fix)](http://grack.com/blog/2009/04/14/gwt-16-crashes-and-a-fix/comment-page-1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.06
```

This is not the latest JDK out there.
Could you try with Java 6 b10 or later, and check if the same issue repeats itself?

Since the [update 10](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javase/java6u10/), a number of improvements have been added,, and the compilation in this instance may prove to be more reliable.

So for instance, try the latest jdk you can find ([jdk6u16](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/webnotes/6u16.html))